# PL/SQL: Statement ignored in trigger

Tags: plsql

I am really confused with PLSQL error messages

The following errors are returned:

```
Error at line 13: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

1. create or replace TRIGGER trg before insert on pacient for each row
2. declare
3. rr varchar(3);
```

It told me that I have an error on line 13, but it shows me line 3 :(. Any idea how to orientate in those messages? Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
 create or replace TRIGGER trg before insert on pacient for each row
 declare
  rr varchar(3);
  mm varchar(3);
  dd varchar(3);
  abc varchar(4);
  x varchar(2);
begin
  rr:=substr (:new.num, 1, 2);
  mm:=substr (:new.num, 3, 2);
  dd:=substr (:new.num, 5, 2);
  abc:=substr (:new.num, 7, 3); 
  x:=substr (:new.num, 10, 1);
  if mod (to_number(rr || mm || dd || abc))<>to_number(x) then raise_application_error(-20500,'wrong    number');
  end if;   
end;
```

Comment: Do not, under any circumstances, do as suggested in the comment by @Mihai. Even if the assignment via SQL didn't cause unnecessary overhead, selecting from the table that fires the trigger will cause a mutating table error.

Answer (score 2):

The `MOD` function accepts **two** parameters.

I guess what you want to achieve is this (really just guessing):

```
  if mod (to_number(rr || mm || dd || abc),to_number(x)) != 0 then  
      raise_application_error(-20500,'wrong    number');
  end if;
```

Do you know what `MOD` does? E.g. `MOD(15,6)` is 3 and `MOD(18,6)` is 0.

Maybe you can edit your question and let us know a bit what this all is for.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed is that Mod needs another parameter. You need to specify what value you want to divide your number by to return the remainder.